# Replacing Text in PNG Image With Gimp 2

Tags: gimp

[image]I've a transparent PNG image i'm using for a button on a web page.  I'd like to be able to replace the images text with some other text using Gimp 2.  Any idea's how i can easily achieve this?  I'm a complete novice to GIMP!

Comment: pngs are not vectorial and so I think you can't edit the test. The way to perform such action depends on the undelying button. Is it monochromatic? Is it flat? Does it have a gradient? Of course, the simpler the button, the easier the intervention. I encourage you to post a sample button, so we can understand the problem.

Comment: thanks for your response, to be honest i'm not sure if its monochromatic or flat, how can i tell easily? I'll attach the button now.

Comment: Please use Gimp for a little while to get yourself familiar with the application before posting questions about it.  I liken your question to someone who is asking how to change a transmission but yet has never driven the car to understand what the transmission does.

Comment: Its not rocket science, so changing the text in an image isn't comparable to changing the transmission in a car! Thanks for your suggestion all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button has a top-down gradient but it should be easy to do the trick.
To get the job done, I'll suggest you to follow these steps:

1. obtain a template button, i.e. a button *without* text.
2. modify the template at will, to get button with any kind of text

**addressing point 1**

Please notice that the gradient of the button is vertical and homogeneous. This really simplify the work: simply, drag a little selection on the left side of the button big enough to cover the height of the text, as shown below

[image: selection]

then you have to copy and paste the selection in a new layer (L1). Move the layer L1 to the right (use the arrow key to preserve vertical alignment) to cover the white text, then copy the L1 to a new layer (L2). Now you have another layer to put on the side of L1 to cover another piece of text. Iterate until the text is all covered. Now you can merge all the layers.

[image: button template]

**addressing point 2**

You have your button template! The last thing to do is to add the text. Choose the text tool and position the cursor in the middle of the button to write the new label. I tried to reproduce the shadow effect of the original text by setting an internal shadow with 50% of opacity, 90 degrees direction and 1px of distance.

Here you can find the png template. I did this tutorial in PS for it is the program I have at hand.

[image: button template]

Answer (score 0):

You cant. PNG Text can't be changed when exported.

1. Create a Button.
2. Add Layers for each text you want to use.
3. Deactivate the the layers except the one needed and export.